# PhpStorm - Save different session states for the same project

Tags: ide, phpstorm

Without creating a new project for each bug/ticket I have to work in within a project, is it possible to save the open files for each of the different bugs/ticket I am working on.

As a very simple example, I am working on Project **Golf** and have two bugs. #1 - Add CRUD functionality for **Player**. #2 - Add CRUD functionality for **Course**.

Within Bug #1 I am working on files `views/players/index.php`, `views/players/add.php`, `views/players/edit.php` and `views/players/view.php`

Within Bug #2 I am working on files `views/courses/index.php`, `views/courses/add.php`, `views/courses/edit.php` and `views/courses/view.php`

I would like to be able to easily switch between bug by opening project **Golf > Bug #1** or **Golf > bug #2** and open the required files that I am working on. The current functionality for me is that PhpStorm will open whatever files I was last working on within that project. If I switch to a completely new bug with completely different I then need to go and reopen them all again.

Although I could create a new project for each bug, this feels a bit cumbersome and the Project Manager screen would also become very cluttered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [integration with an Issue Tracking System in PhpStorm](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Integration+with+an+Issue+Tracking+System+in+PhpStorm) then IDE will load your tabs that you had open when last time worked on that particular ticket/task.

Regardless if you use such integration or not -- this functionality is called "Contexts" and you can switch between them using `Tools | Tasks & Contexts | Load Context`.

More on this in official Help pages: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/switching-between-contexts.html?search=context

Comment: Awesome. Works perfectly!

Comment: Didn't know this feature, useful indeed. ;)