# PhpStorm Task Profiles within the same project

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I was wondering if PhpStorm has the option to swap or create different profiles for different tasks within the same project.

Here is what I mean. Lets say I create a Project called Project A for a Website and this website gives me **2 Tasks** that require me to open different files to work on different templates.

- During **Task 1**, I open 5 Files and work on them, I finish my work and tell the website owner for feedback;
- then I start working on **Task 2** and open 3 other different files, work on them and I get feedback for **Task 1**;
- and I need to work on **Task 1** again, but I have just closed all the tabs for **Task 1**.

  Now I need to look where the files were that I worked on, but it would be nicer if I could create a profile called (**Task 1**) and when I chose it, it opens all the files that I worked on, or open all the files that I saved for that task. Just like **Google Browser bookmarks**.

Is this possible?

Comment: If I got you correctly, then sure, It's called **Tasks & Contexts**. If you use VCS or task management app (GitHub Issues/ YouTrack tickets/ Jira etc.) that's hat Tasks are for. Contexts is basically a set of files and can be used alone. But they work better when used together (you switching a Task and it loads corresponding Context for you). An actual help page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/managing-tasks-and-context.html

Comment: See 1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/35841826/783119 2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/35335151/783119. Let me know which one of these 2 existing answers better covers your question.

Comment: Thanks, first Question and Answer is what i needed. 1) stackoverflow.com/a/35841826/783119