# How to make the tab group?

Tags: android-studio, phpstorm

I am working on `Android Studio` and `PhpStorm`. I work with many features in the same project.
Sometimes I must stop a current feature when the employer wants a feature that is urgent and some feature must break for a short time to wait for the employer to test/think/.....

So, I want to make the group tab of files of each feature like a group tab in `Edge`.
How to do that?
[image]

Comment: I guess you are after Contexts (a set of tabs that can be loaded/saved/closed at once; can also be linked to a specific Task ticket -- the IDE will load them when you switch to that Task) -- have a look  https://stackoverflow.com/a/35841826/783119 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/35335151/783119

Comment: As to actual opened tabs grouping in the editor (have named groups visible at the same time/right now) -- not really. You can have split areas and groups your tabs this way (the same file can be opened in more than 1 split) but nothing like on your screenshot.

Comment: Thank you @LazyOne. I found a way to swap feature editing in PhpStorm now but how about android studio?

Comment: *"I found a way to swap feature editing"* not sure what you mean. Are you talking about Contexts (that I have mentioned in my first comment)? if so -- it should be available in Android Studio as well. It comes via bundled Task Management plugin. See if you have it in AS.

Comment: Hi @LazyOne, I posted my answer that is what I want. I don't know if is that called `Contexts`.

Comment: **You are using just that.** Context is a set of editor tabs (opened files). Task, in simple words, is a Context + a link to some task in your Issue Tracking system (Jira, Trello, YouTrack, GitHub Issues, GitLab, Bugzilla, Mantis etc -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/managing-tasks-and-context.html). What you did in your answer -- you are actually using that but with local tasks (not connected to any specific Issue Tracking system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this. I noticed a default task menu at the left top.
[image]

This is not a tab group but this is similar and can be done what I want.

You can try by pressing `alt` + `shift` + `t` to open this. You will see this.
[image]

Then click `+ Open Task...`. You will see this.
[image]

Click `Create New Task` and press your task name like test then click ok.
[image]

After that, you can switch tasks (tab group) by pressing `alt` + `shift` + `t` and selecting what you want.
[image]

This is available on `PhpStorm` and `Android Studio`.

This is called `Context`. You can see it more with [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/managing-tasks-and-context.html). [Cr.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/136596997?noredirect=1)